# Pandas replace with dict and condition

Tags: python, pandas

In Pandas in Python you have the function df.replace(), which you can give a dict to change the values in a column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                   'C': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})
df.replace('A': {0: 10, 3: 100})
```

Is it possible to add a condition to this? For example that it will only replace the values in the A column if the value in the B column is smaller than 8.

Comment: sounds like you are looking for `np.where`, not `df.replace`

Answer (score 1):

Using `where`:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].replace({0: 10, 3: 100}).where(df['B'].lt(8), df['A'])
```

output:

```
    A  B  C
0  10  5  a
1   1  6  b
2   2  7  c
3   3  8  d
4   4  9  e
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.update(df['A'][df['B'] < 8].replace({0: 10, 3: 100}))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
      A  B  C
0  10.0  5  a
1   1.0  6  b
2   2.0  7  c
3   3.0  8  d
4   4.0  9  e
```

Notice how `A` at row `3` is not `100`, but `3.0` (the old value). Because `B` at row `3` is `8`, which, per your condition, is not less then `8`.